# Referencing List by indexVar in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have nested list in my lightning component and now I want  to refer records of list using indexVar. 
Has anyone done this before?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="row" indexVar="rowCnt">

Like `{!row[rowCnt]}?`

</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: May you add some example code, why you need this?

Comment: Also, share the `records` **attribute type**.

Comment: Why do you want to this?

Answer (score 4):

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="row" indexVar="rowCnt">
    {!row}
</aura:iteration>
```

will do the trick. Getting the value dynamically would look like this, {!v.records[rowCnt]} but it doesn't work in lightning.

> Failed to save undefined: expecting a positive integer, found 'rowCnt'

You only are allowed to use static integers like: `{!v.records[0]}`

In case you need the index in your controller, you could use a regular html element like a div and pass the Index with a [data-* attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp), unfortunately this won't work with any lightning component, only pure html.

```
<div onclick="{!c.doStuff}" data-index="{!rowCnt}">

doStuff : function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var index = evt.currentTarget.dataset.index;
}
```