# What is the best way to use map of sobjects in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

In Classic/Visualforce I can iterate through Map using apex:repeat. What is the best way to do that in lightning? I want to display key and some fields from sObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [aura:iteration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_iteration.htm)

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.Objects}" var="obj" indexVar="index">
   {!index}: {!obj.foo__c}
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

You won't be able to iterate over maps, you can only iterate over lists.
And you can't use the index to fetch data dynamically: `{!v.Keys[index]}` or anything similar won't work. To solve your key problem, you would need to create a component (instantiated in your iteration) that you pass in your object (and your key), and in there you would know how to display additional information, preparing it in Javascript.

You might find more details about the key issue in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/198039/2513)