# Dynamically Add row functionality in lightning component(irrespective of sobject)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

My idea is to create a dynamic add/delete row functionality without specifying a particular object to attribute. I got my hands dirty by developing a component as follows:

Add_Del_Row.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="cusObj" type="Object"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="headings" type="List" ></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldAPiNames" type="List" ></aura:attribute>

    <table>
        <thead>
         <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.headings}" var="h">
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!h}">{!h}</div>
            </th>
        </aura:iteration>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldAPiNames}" var="f">
                <td><ui:inputText class="slds-input" value="{!v.cusObj.f}"></td>
            </aura:iteration>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    <br/>
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Add" onclick="{! c.save }"></lightning:button>
</aura:component>
```

Add_Del_Row.js:

```
save:function(cmp,evt,helper){
    var selectedVals = cmp.get('v.cusObj');
    console.log('selects--'+ selectedVals);
}
```

Finally My app is as follows:

```
<c: Add_Del_Row headings="['Name','Phone','Email','Age']"
               fieldAPiNames="['Name','Phone','Email','Age__c']" cusObj="Contact"></c:Add_Row_cmp>
```

Table was rendered perfect. But the values given as input are not able to accessible in .js controller. Is there a way to reference them?

Comment: This `{!v.cusObj.f}` is no valid syntax. Check [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/198034/2513) for more information

Comment: In this scenerio you want to create Component dynamically,you cant set `{!v.cusObj.f}` Like this in markup. check link for more details https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

Comment: vignesh -- When i try using $A.createCompoents , result was not getting in column formats. If i create two ui:inputText, they're styling vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: @Rv1 can you edit the question with latest code.

Comment: @vignesh I have created another test component for that. Didn't include it in this component

Comment: @Rv1 did you created another component for `input:text` or you created `td and inputText` dynamically with the same component? If you post a code it bit easy to say what you have done wrong.

Comment: @vignesh Created only inputText in $A.Createcomponents and placed it under HTML Table <tr>. But,didn't got the output as expected.Can we put td in createComponents itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69333/discussion-between-vignesh-and-rv1).